# How box topology is finer than product topology?

Tags: general-topology

I just studied Munkres, but there is only one line that box topology is finer no any explaination.
I think i just need to show tha basis elements of box topology are contained in the basis element of product topology but i don't know how??

Comment: Start with the definitions...

Comment: I can't understand why the basis elements of product topology are equal to X(alpha)

Comment: If you're confused about some part of the proof, ask specifically about that.